# Entity Framework Paging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, entity-framework-4

I have been looking for code that if I can paging the big data in EF, For example from 1 to 100... or more, the web application is really slow.
I have code here but I couldn't found a solution yet.

I'am really need to make the data in page or make the data view faster 
the records the are more then (1,5000,000) records.
Please guys if someone have any code or solution for EF paging or the data can be faster reply to me.

Thank you guys,

[Codes]

```
var openComplaintsAssignedToOffice = individual.Office.AssignedComplaints
                                                      .ToArray()
                                                      .Where(n => n.Individuals.Any(e => e.Employed))
                                                      .ToArray() ; 

if (!complaintModel.ShowClosedComplaints)
{
    openComplaintsAssignedToOffice = openComplaintsAssignedToOffice.Where(c => c.CurrentStatus != ComplaintStatus.Closed)
                                                                   .ToArray();
}

complaintModel.OpenComplaintsAssignedToMyOffice = openComplaintsAssignedToOffice.OrderByDescending(c => c.UpdatedDateTime)
                                                                                .ToArray();
complaintModel.OpenComplaintsAssignedToMyOffice = openComplaintsAssignedToOffice.OrderByDescending(c => c.UpdatedDateTime)
                                                                                .ToArray();
return complaintModel;
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the `.Skip()` and `.Take()` functions?

Comment: You're asking a very trivial question accompanied by code that doesn't seem to be related to it. Or, to put it more exactly, code that seems to cause issues in itself.

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't indicate specifically where you're looking to page your data, so for simplicity I'm going to assume it's here:

```
individual.Office.AssignedComplaints
```

(Though, as a side note, you seem to be pretty cavalier about throwing in a `.ToArray()` here and there.  Understand that this could *drastically* impact performance by forcing the system to load *many* records into memory before performing a filter on those records which could have better been performed on the data source itself.)

You can use the `.Skip()` and `.Take()` functions to effectively page the results.  For example, let's say you have these values:

```
var pageSize = 10;
var currentPage = 3;  // 0-indexed, of course
```

Given those, you would expect to see records 30-39, correct?  So you'd use those values to page the data:

```
individual.Office.AssignedComplaints.Skip(pageSize * currentPage).Take(pageSize)
```

This would result in skipping the first 30 records (0-29) and taking the next 10 records, ignoring the rest.  Effectively returning "page 3" of the total result set.

This paging can be applied anywhere in your overall expression tree where a result set can be filtered.  Before or after sorting, before or after a `.Where()` clause, etc.  It's really up to you where it would logically belong based on how you're intending to shape and present the data.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you'll use the [`Skip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`Take()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx) methods to handle paging data. `Skip()` will determine how many elements to "skip" to define a starting point for the page and `Take()` will determine how many elements to grab.

```
// This will skip the first 10 records and take the next 20
var page = data.Skip(10).Take(20);
```

**Consider [Deferred Execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx)**

A very important thing to consider when handling this is that you want to defer execution as long as possible. Methods like `ToList()` or `ToArray()` will actually store your values in memory, which you want to avoid, especially with large data sets.

If you can avoid calling methods like these, you'll ensure that the query itself is only executed a single time (and thus only returning a page of records instead of your entire dataset, which is then paged in memory).

You could likely refactor your code to use paging as seen below :

```
// Define your page size and initial page
var page = 0;
var pageSize = 20;
// Get any open complaints
var openComplaints = individual.Office.AssignedComplaints.Where(n => n.Individuals.Any(e => e.Employed));
// Determine if complaints should be shown
if (!complaintModel.ShowClosedComplaints)
{
     openComplaints = openComplaints.Where(c => c.CurrentStatus != ComplaintStatus.Closed);                                                            
}
// Finally order and page your data
return openComplaints.OrderByDescending(c => c.UpdatedDateTime)
                     .Skip(page * pageSize)
                     .Take(pageSize)
                     .ToArray();
```

Comment: I want thank you Rion for your code, it's actually works if I changed to be like this
individual.Office.AssignedComplaints.Skip(pageSize * currentPage).Take(pageSize)